# Would you like a regular chat event for talking about Linguistics?

Tags: discussion, chat-events

When I first set our monthly Linguistics Meeting, someone thought it was a meeting for discussing about Linguistics and not the site itself...

So would you like a regular event, it could be set up weekly, so that everyone meets up and discusses about *any* topic concerning Linguistics?

What are your thoughts? Proposals? Ideas? Opinions?

Comment: Vote here if you think this is a great topic.

Comment: I meant vote up the question part if you think the topic is worth asking, but hey you are more than welcome to vote on the comment too if that's what you're into (-;

Answer (score 3):

Vote up here if you think this is a great idea.

Vote down here if you think it's not.

<sup>(I think it is!)</sup>

Comment: I've upvoted Q but downvoted this A. I think linguists, likewise professionals in any other area, tend to pursue specific questions instead of just saying hello to each other during meet-ups. On the other hand, scheduling meet-ups **on specific topics** sounds valuable. The most upvoted Q's or categories seem to be a good gauge what's most important. What about a certain Q on [tag:phonology]?

Comment: @bytebuster If you have ideas or similar stuff about this proposal, consider posting an answer where you explain your point of view. It might be helpful.

Comment: @Alenanno I'm rather an amateur, so I'd better listen for ideas from people who know better. Just expressed my point. :)

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to phrase the questions, especially for the ones that come from interested non-linguists, or untrained armchair linguists like myself. But yeah if we have the even say once per month then the highest voted new topics both in the main site and the meta site would certainly be good places to start. And controversial new topics too - not just ones that got consistently upvoted.

Comment: @bytebuster You don't need to be a PhD linguist to help with this. I'm not one either! :) As long as we're not writing a thesis, opinions are welcome!